# Bash script executable manually but only partially via udev rule

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, udev, ssmtp

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and I wrote a script to take pictures and send an email with ssmtp when someone removes a USB device from my computer.

the udev rule works fine and execute the script but only the "picture taking" part works, not the email sending.

when I execute the script myself in a terminal, everything goes well, the pictures are taken, the email is sent. It just doesn't work when it is triggered by the udev rule.

the rule:

```
ACTION=="remove", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", RUN+="/home/jensen/Documents/script.sh"
```

the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/jensen
fswebcam -r 640x480 --jpeg 85 webcamshot1.jpg
fswebcam -r 640x480 --jpeg 85 webcamshot2.jpg
fswebcam -r 640x480 --jpeg 85 webcamshot3.jpg

echo "Subject: test mail" | /usr/sbin/sendmail -v testmail@gmail.com
```

and the ssmtp config:

```
root=**********@gmail.com
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
hostname=jensen
AuthUser=**********@gmail.com
AuthPass=**********
UseSTARTTLS=yes
UseTLS=yes
FromLineOverride=yes
```

I tried changing the permissions on the script file with chmod but nothing works.
what could be the issue ?

Comment: Your script is running as `root`. Can `root` send email on your system?

Comment: You could put this script elsewhere (`~jensen/bin`) and execute it with `sudo -u jensen /home/jensen/bin/script` in your udev rule.